# Unable to change the url path in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using [creative time free react dashboard][1]. I am not able to change the url path of a page.

I have create a route in the routes.js:

```
    {
    id: 7,
    path: "/forgot-password",
    invisible: true,
    name: "P.I. Operations",
    icon: "nc-icon nc-single-02",
    component: ForgotPassword,
    layout: "/admin",
},
```

In the index.js of the app i have added the route like this:

```
<Route
    path="/forgot-password"
    render={(props) => <ForgotPasswordLayout {...props} />}
  />
```

When ever i visit the http://localhost:3000/forgot-password I just git a blank page. I have been trying to fix this for the last few days. I request you guys to help me fix this, thanks in advance.
[1]: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard-material-ui-v4

Comment: Do you really need the `props` and the `render` prop in the `Route` component? You can also use the `component` props to directly use `ForgotForgotPasswordLayout` component on that route.

Comment: @UsmanSabuwala

Thanks for the comment,  Can you give me an example on how I can use the component props to directly use the ForgotPasswordLayout component on the route?

Comment: remove the `render` prop or attribute. Use the `component` prop and pass the `ForgotPasswordLayout` in it. Or even better just expand the `Route` component and put `ForgotPasswordLayout` directly. Also refer the docs if you want https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route

`<Route  path="/forgot-password"><ForgotPasswordLayout /></Route>`

Comment: Thank you @UsmanSabuwala, It worked. I am now able to render the page the way I want to. Thank you once again for your help. :-)

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` are you using? From your project directory please run `npm list react-router-dom` and report back.

Comment: @DrewReese I am using react-router-dom version 5.0.0

Comment: What you have for a `Route` should be working then, it's just passing the route props through to the `ForgotPasswordLayout` component. If possible could you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to use the `component` prop or add the component as children in the `<Route>` component.

```
<Route
    path="/forgot-password"
    component={ForgotPasswordLayout}
/>
// OR
<Route path="/forgot-password">
  <ForgotPasswordLayout />
</Route>
```